# sed or awk in bash to format input list > output list and escape special characters

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Hope someone can help me with a sed / awk pipe which I can use in bash to take an input list like this

```
Battleztar Bazinga
com.plumanalytics
ECCP/1.0
Go!Zilla
GT::WWW
MegaIndex.ru
MS Web Services Client
POE-Component-Client-HTTP
```

and give an output list like this

```
Battleztar\ Bazinga
com\.plumanalytics
ECCP\/1\.0
Go\!Zilla
GT\:\:WWW
MegaIndex\.ru
MS\ Web\ Services\ Client
POE\-Component\-Client\-HTTP
```

Basically escaping all special characters and spaces with backslash `\`

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus, I do understand I should do that, my head is really just not with me today at all and been ill for a week so really battling at the moment with the simplest of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]_]/\\&/g' file

Battleztar\ Bazinga
com\.plumanalytics
ECCP\/1\.0
Go\!Zilla
GT\:\:WWW
MegaIndex\.ru
MS\ Web\ Services\ Client
POE\-Component\-Client\-HTTP
```

- Negated bracket expression `[^[:alnum:]_]` will match any character that is not an alpha-numeric and underscore.
- In replacement `\\&` will place `\` before matched text.

Comment: Thats works like utter magic, thank you so much. My final command line in my bash script is `cat input.txt | sed 's/\\ / /g' | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]_]/\\&/g' > inputtmp.txt && mv inputtmp.txt output.txt` thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The reason for my extra sed pipe `sed 's/\\ / /g'` just to clarify is the input file being converted has `\ ` in it so I strip them out first.

Comment: You can probably do: `sed 's/\\ / /g; s/[^[:alnum:]_]/\\&/g'  input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Thanks a million, works perfectly. You saved my day big time, I owe you one.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"\\\\&")+1' infile
```

If you have `gawk`, then you may use

```
gawk -i inplace 'gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"\\\\&")+1' infile
```

which will modify original file,

to keep backup before

```
gawk -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak -i inplace 'gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"\\\\&")+1' infile
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the sed works for me but I also need to start learning awk and gawk too so I will also test these out for good measure and start improving on learning new things :)

Comment: Thats great keep learning, please make a note, above one escapes underscore (`_`), char too, if you want to exclude, then add it in bracket, and certainly `sed` is better for tasks like find and replace, and in current context, so solution given by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) suits the best.

Comment: I tried your first awk `awk 'gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"\\\\&")+1' infile` but it is doing this with the spaces `Battleztar\\\ Bazinga` everything else is perfect including the one's with underscores which I do have some of in my list just need to remedy the `\\\ ` issue with spaces.